# LINQ How to Remove Empty Elements at End of Collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an array of strings that has a fixed size of 10. Some elements may be `null`. I want to use LINQ to remove the elements with the value `null` from the array, but only at the end.

Input:

```
"Hello", null, "World", null, null, null, null, null, null, null
```

Output:

```
"Hello", null, "World"
```

So the output array contains all elements except for the trailing ones containing `null`.

I thought of reversing the IEnumerable, then doing a SkipWhile and reversing it again.
This would be possible and would be not much of a performance penalty in my case, but I am curious if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a different LINQ variant that works for any enumerable (`string[]`, `List<string>`) you can try the following which uses [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netcore-3.1) and [`SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netcore-3.1):

```
using System.Linq;

string[] strings = { "Hello", null, "World", null, null, null, null, null, null };
var result = strings.Reverse()
                    .SkipWhile(c => c is null)
                    .Reverse()
                    .ToArray();
```

Note that this is *definitely* not the most performant, I'm just offering a different version than those already posted.

Since you have an "array of strings", I assume you mean literally a `string[]` and not a `List<string>`. As an alternative to LINQ you can use operations over the array with [`Array.FindLastIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findlastindex?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_FindLastIndex__1___0___System_Predicate___0__) + [`AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=netcore-3.1#System_MemoryExtensions_AsSpan__1___0___System_Int32_System_Int32_) + `ToArray` (note that all solutions here forward assume that it's possible for your array to be *all* `null`s):

```
string[] strings = { "Hello", null, "World", null, null, null, null, null, null };
var idx = Array.FindLastIndex(strings, c => c != null);

var result = idx >= 0 ? strings.AsSpan(0, idx + 1).ToArray() 
                      : Array.Empty<string>();
```

If `Span<T>` is not available to you, we could combine with LINQ's [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var idx = Array.FindLastIndex(strings, c => c != null);
var result = idx >= 0 ? strings.Take(idx + 1).ToArray() 
                      : Array.Empty<string>();
```

Or without LINQ:

```
var idx = Array.FindLastIndex(strings, c => c != null);
var result = Array.Empty<string>();
if (idx >= 0)
{
   result = new string[idx +1 ];
   Array.Copy(strings, 0, result, 0, idx + 1);
}
```

If you have later C# features, we can use [`System.Range`/`System.Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) and create a sub-array of the existing array:

```
string[] strings = { "Hello", null, "World", null, null, null, null, null, null };

var idx = Array.FindLastIndex(strings, c => c != null);  
var result = idx >= 0 ? strings[..(idx + 1)] 
                      : Array.Empty<string>();
```

Or as a (kind of hard to read) one-liner if that's what you are after:

```
var result = Array.FindLastIndex(strings, c => c != null) is int idx && idx >= 0 ? strings[..(idx + 1)] : Array.Empty<string>();
```

### Removing Elements from Array

You're title asks to *remove* elements. While I'm fairly sure you're looking to create a new collection (given your mention of LINQ), I figured I'd point out that you can't really remove elements from an array--they are fixed in size. However you *can* make use of [`Array.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netcore-3.1) to "crop" your array:

```
var idx = Array.FindLastIndex(strings, c => c != null); 
if (idx >= 0)
   Array.Resize(ref strings, idx + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your work! Yes, I expressed myself in a wrong way. What I want is a IEnumerable<string> that contains all array element except for the trailing null's.
My aray is really small, and I have no special performance or memory requirements, so every approach would be OK. However, I wondered what the most elegant approach would be.

Answer (score 3):

If your collection is a `List` you can use `FindLastIndex`:

```
var x = new List<string> { "Hello", null, "World", null, null, null, null, null, null, null};
x = x.Take(x.FindLastIndex(s => s != null) + 1).ToList();
```

If you are working with another collection type you can try something like this:

```
x.Take(x.Select((s, index) => (s, index))
    .Aggregate(-1, (acc, curr) => curr.s != null ? curr.index : acc) + 1)
```

So it is definitely not an elegant one.

If your collection is guaranteed to have at least one not null element you can make it a little bit prettier:

```
x.Take(x.Select((s, index) => (s, index)).Last(t => t.s != null).index + 1)
```

Or just hide the ugliness by writing your own extension method which will implement `FindLastIndex` logic for `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that doesn't require allocations, random-access collections, or iterating the collection multiple times.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TrimEnd<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        int nulls = 0;
        foreach (var e in col)
        {
            if ( e == null || e.Equals(default(T)) )
            {
                nulls += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                while (nulls > 0)
                {
                    nulls -= 1;
                    yield return default(T);
                }
                yield return e;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one! I only doubt the `e.Equals(default(T))` part. That would trim trailing zeros from a list of integers, for example. Perhaps it's just a question of definition.

Comment: That's the intent.  To be able to 0-trim a byte array with the same method.  And I _think_ that for `TrimEnd<Byte>` either the IL or compiled code will remove the null check, since generic methods are code-gen'd once for all reference types, but separately for each value type.

Comment: Good to know. This method is by far the most elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last index of not *null* or *empty* value from the list then get all values before last index

```cs
List<string> data = new List<string> { "Hello", null, "World", null, null, null, null, null, null, null };
int lastIndex = data.FindLastIndex(a => a != null);
data = data.Where((value, index) => index <= lastIndex).ToList();
```

**Result :** `"Hello", null, "World"`